# Find 1st Letter of every word in a string

Tags: bash, sed, grep

How would I find the first letter of a word contained within a string using bash.

For example

Code:

```
str="my-custom-string'
```

I would want to find m,c,s.  I know how to find the very first letter, but this is slightly more complicated.
Many thanks,

Comment: "I know how to find the very first letter", don't tell us, show us [what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) and where you got stuck.

Comment: str='my-custom-string'; echo ${str:0:1}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ echo 'my-custom-string' | egrep -o '\b\w'
m
c
s
```

Answer (score 2):

Pure Bash using parameter substitution. Remove minus, select first character of each word:

```
str="my-custom-string"

for word in ${str//-/ }; do
    echo "${word:0:1}"
done
```

Result

```
m
c
s
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `sed` version:

```
echo 'my-custom-string' | sed 's/\(^\|-\)\(.\)[^-]*/\2\n/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed);

```
echo 'my-custom-string' | sed 's/\B.//g;y/-/,/'
m,c,s
```

or:

```
echo 'my-custom-string' | sed 's/\B.//g;y/-/\n/'
m
c
s
```